# C vs C++ - cross-platform

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

I have a very quick question to which I havn't found an answer for.
Are there any major platforms (Windows, MacOS, unix, linux, Android, iOS, etc....) out there that supports C but not C++?

Thanks

Comment: The PIC-Series microcontrollers have only a C compiler (but not C++) supplied by the manufacturer. Arduino supports C only (although you can hack the AVR compiler to a subset of C++). They're the only ones off the top of my head

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C and C++ are not operating system dependant. If there is a compiler that can compile the C/C++ code to execute not he current CPU. All is good.

Comment: The languages and compilers are not OS dependent per se, but the *runtimes* are.

Answer (score 4):

Since C is a subset of C++, you'll definitely bump into some environment that supports C but no C++. Whether such a platform may be called 'major' by any standards is another question. (There was a C compiler for the C64, but no C++ compiler to my knowledge. The C64 was absolutely a major platform :)

Comment: The C64 was also 25 years ago. There weren't many C++ compilers around then.

Comment: I think Clang can compile C++ into C. So in principle you could combine that with your given C compiler to compile any standard C++ program to your target platform. (Not sure if Clang produces purely standard C, though, or if there are library dependecies.)

Comment: Note, C is not a subset of C++;  even in the case of C89, there are things (the ternary operator, for one) that work differently for the two.  The point of the post still stands, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you got me curious though and I found this site that anyone considering cross-platform development should read [Ten Rules for Cross-Platform Development](http://www.ski-epic.com/source_code_essays/ten_rules_for_writing_cross_platform_c_source_code.html).  I personally believe learning how to do things right from the "get-go" is essential.

Answer (score 0):

simply put no, the question is how you program, if a compiler is available for the platform and if your libraries are available for the target platform.